# Async AJAX JSON calls over WIFI to Internet randomly very quick, slow or no response: Normal or something wrong?

Tags: ajax, json, performance, wifi

My web application is randomly very quick, slow or getting no response with async AJAX JSON calls when used on Windows 8 Pad over WIFI to Internet but ultra-fast when used on laptop over wired Internet.

Is this normal when using a WIFI connection? Is there something I should take into account when designing async AJAX calls over WIFI?

Measured WIFI performance

Download speed: 4.33 Mbps
Upload speed: 4.47 Mbps

Measured LAN performance

Download speed: 48.71 Mbps
Upload speed: 6.68 Mbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building AJAX web applications used over a WIFI connection you have to set a timeout (e.g. 1000ms) and send the request again if the response is taking time. It's possible that due to changing latency the response may arrive only after a couple of minutes or within a second. With the help of a timeout and resending you make sure that your response will have a better chance to arrive in a reasonable time.

```
$.ajax({ ... timeout: 1000,
             error: function (request, status, err) {
                    if (status == "timeout") {
                      // Send again in case of a timeout
                       $.ajax(this);
                    }
             }
});
```